# Switching Debug configuration to Release turns off Devart.Data.PostgreSql namespace

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2017, devart

When I build Debug configuration, `Devart.Data.PostgreSql` is visible to my c# code. When I switch configuration to Release, it is "could not be found". The nuget package 7.7.832 (tried to upgrade to the latest 7.20, no dice) is still showing as installed. What kind of trick is required to build a Release with this package? I do not believe that such a trivial task should require a lot of R&D, but I did look on their web site and found only some rudimentary simple instructions related to dbForge. Maybe I did not look long enough.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{9...2}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>PPostgreSql</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>PPostgreSql</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE NETFRAMEWORK</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE NETFRAMEWORK</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reproduce the issue. Open *.csproj with XML Editor and compare your Debug and Release configurations to find out the cause of the problem. If this doesn't help, [send us](https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) a test project for reproducing.

Comment: I am not sure what I am supposed to compare. I've added the configurations to the question.

Comment: dotConnect for PostgreSQL includes two sets of assemblies: .NET Framework (C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\dotConnect\PostgreSQL\) and .NET Standard (https://www.nuget.org/packages/devart.data.postgresql). With .NET Framework v4.7.1, please use the provider assemblies from C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\dotConnect\PostgreSQL\.